# Нужно поменять значение data-rel="prettyPhoto[rel-978-1349792375]" Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Есть страница с фотографиями сделанная в билдере WPBakery
Структура изображений такая :
Одна картинка квартиры.
медиа галлерея из 6 картинок.
Одна картинка квартиры.
Вопрос вот в чем:Когда я нажимаю на картинку сверху или снизу - открывается только она и не могу листать дальше.
если нажать на любую из медиа галлереи могу листать но нет верхней и нижней.
в браузере через код элемента получалось сделать то что мне нужно,но я не знаю в какой файл это нужно вписывать?